# get distinct row and use coalesce if id not exist in other table

Tags: mysql, join, max, distinct, coalesce

I have two tables:

**Job_Order**

```
-id
-creation_date
-assigned_to
-job_ordertype
-client
```

**Job_Order_Stage**

```
-id
-stage
-date 
-job_order(foreign key to job_order)
```

I want to get all rows in the `job_order`  and set stage to 0 if id not exist in the Job_Order_Stage. And I also want to get only the row with `max(stage)`  if same `job_order` found in `job_order_stage`. How am I going to do it?

I have here the query:

```
SELECT 
    a.id,a.creation_date,
    e.user_name,c.operation,
    c.system_,d.name,
    Coalesce((s.stage), 0) as stage_name
FROM job_order a
INNER JOIN account b ON a.assigned_to=b.id
INNER JOIN job_order_type c ON a.job_order_type=c.id
INNER JOIN user e ON b.user=e.user_id
INNER JOIN client d ON a.client=d.id
LEFT JOIN job_order_stage s ON s.job_order = a.id
```

My problem with this sql statement is that, it displays all job orders and its duplicate having different stage. How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one gets all your job_orders that aren't in job_order_stage

```
select job_order.*
  from job_order
    left join job_order_stage
      on job_order.id = job_order_stage.job_order
  where job_order_stage.job_order is null;
```

This one gets your `max(stage)` where the job IS in job_order_stage

```
select job_order.id, max(job_order_stage.stage)
  from job_order 
    inner join job_order_stage
      on job_order.id = job_order_stage.job_order
  group by job_order.id;
```

Or did you somehow want them to be combined? Which would be something like this:

```
select job_order.*, max(coalesce(job_order_stage.stage, 0)) stage
  from job_order
    left join job_order_stage
      on job_order.id = job_order_stage.job_order
  group by job_order.id
```

This makes use of / abuses mysqls special handling of `group by`, but in this instance it should be fine.

**update from comments**

```
select *
  from (
    select job_order.*, max(coalesce(job_order_stage.stage, 0)) stage
      from job_order
        left join job_order_stage
          on job_order.id = job_order_stage.job_order
      group by job_order.id
 ) q 
 where stage = 2;
```

Comment: I want them to be combine if possible. Is it possible?

Comment: @d_unknown no problem. if it gave you the values you wanted, feel free to click the accept answer tick mark :)

Comment: what if I only want to get the row with max(job_order_stage.stage)==2

Comment: use this query as the input / source of another query. ie. wrap another select around this one, with `where stage = 2`

Comment: i made it like this: `SELECT a.id,a.creation_date,e.user_name,c.system_,d.name,
    Coalesce(max(s.stage), 0) as stage_name 
    FROM job_order a
    INNER JOIN account b
    ON a.assigned_to=b.id
       INNER JOIN job_order_type c
       ON a.job_order_type=c.id
       INNER JOIN user e
       ON b.user=e.user_id
       INNER JOIN client d
       ON a.client=d.id 
       LEFT JOIN job_order_stage s
       ON s.job_order = a.id 
       WHERE a.assigned_to='$id' and s.stage=(select max(stage) from job_order_stage where job_order=a.id and stage=1)
       group by a.id`

Comment: but the result is just the same with these query: `SELECT a.id,a.creation_date,e.user_name,c.system_,d.name,
    Coalesce(max(s.stage), 0) as stage_name 
    FROM job_order a
    INNER JOIN account b
    ON a.assigned_to=b.id
       INNER JOIN job_order_type c
       ON a.job_order_type=c.id
       INNER JOIN user e
       ON b.user=e.user_id
       INNER JOIN client d
       ON a.client=d.id 
       LEFT JOIN job_order_stage s
       ON s.job_order = a.id 
       WHERE a.assigned_to='$id' and s.stage=1
       group by a.id`

Comment: I tried like this but it it returns invalid group function error : `where max(job_order_stage.stage)==2`;